# code structure with several callbacks

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working on a small 4WD rover. I use ultrasonic sensors, and a RPlidar for autonomous navigation and a joy for manual teleoperation.
My aim is quite simple, but i am asking some questions about the right python script architecture.

The main idea is to have a loop which check joy inputs, and update both sonar and laser data
Joy input decide the current mode ('AUTO' or 'MANUAL')

Thus I write this code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import time
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from sensor_msgs.msg import Joy
from rospy_tutorials.msg import Floats
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan 

## MODE

def auto_mode():
    print( sonar_array[0] + sonar_array[1])
    print( laser_array[0] + laser_array[1])
    # detect obstacle
    # compute path
    
## CALLBACKS    

def callback_joy(data):

    if data.buttons[0]<0.5 :
        switchMode = 'AUTO'
    else:
        switchMode = 'MANUAL'
        twist.linear.x = 4*data.axes[1]
        twist.angular.z = 4*data.axes[0]
        
def callback_sonar(data):

    sonar_array = data.data
    #some data filtering and processing
    
def callback_laser(scan):

    laser_array = scan.ranges
    #some data filtering and processing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # initialisation
    print("initialization ")
    
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel',Twist,queue_size=5)
    twist = Twist() 
    rospy.init_node('viva_node', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber('joy', Joy, callback_joy)
    rospy.Subscriber('sonar', Floats, callback_sonar)
    rospy.Subscriber('/scan', LaserScan, callback_laser)
    
    # loop
    print('loop')
    while True:
        print('spin')
        rospy.spin()
        print 'Current Mode is : ',  switch_mode
        
        if switch_mode == 'AUTO':
            auto_mode()
```

But, when i run, this script nothing append except :

> pi@rasberrypi:~ $ rosrun perso_package viva_node_rev3.py

> initialization

> loop

> spin

Then script get stuck and nothing append.
I don't know why, any idea would are welcome.

Matt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263355/code-structure-with-several-callbacks/) by [mattMGN](https://answers.ros.org/users/29874/mattmgn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2017-06-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-08**:
A suggestion: use the [teleop_twist_joy](http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_joy) package instead of converting raw `Joy` msgs to Twists yourself.

**Comment by [mattMGN](https://answers.ros.org/users/29874/mattmgn/) on 2017-06-09**:
I need to switch between manual and auto mode from my joystick, so I am oblige to import raw Joy msgs.
But maybe there is an other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you use rospy.spin(), you're telling the program to sit there and wait (i.e. don't exit) until ros is shutdown. It's mainly used when for when your program just launches some subscribers then there's nothing to do except let the callbacks run when new messages come in.

Since you have a while loop there, the program would not be exiting, so you do not need rospy.spin() in this case. I don't think there is ever a case where you would have an endless while loop and need to use a rospy.spin().

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-06-07**:
It can be a little confusing because in roscpp, I think you would have needed a spinOnce() there to allow the callbacks to be called, but rospy doesn't need that because each subscriber has it's own thread.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-06-07**:
They should use `rospy.sleep()` instead of spin, or better yet switch to a timer callback http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time

**Comment by [mattMGN](https://answers.ros.org/users/29874/mattmgn/) on 2017-06-09**:
Your answer is helpfull, I have removed ropsy.spin() and it is now working. I though that rospy.spin() told callback to be executed. Sorry for this misunderstanding

Matt

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-06-13**:
No problem. If that answers the question please select the check mark to close it out.